# PHP PDO prepared statment - unable to insert boolen value of false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, boolean

I am trying to insert a boolean value with PDO into MySQLdatabase. If `$data['age2']` is `false` the insertion doesn't take place but if `true` then it works. If I use the `->bindParam()` method it works again. But if it was possible I would pass my variables in an associative array. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong. at the bottom of the code I have inserted the code for the creation of the table (I want to insert into) as well. thanks

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '12345';
$dbName = 'pdo';

// set DSN data sorce name
$dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbName}";

// create pdo instance
$pdoConn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdoConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$data = [
    ':fname' => 'Bob',
    ':sname' => 'Desaunois',
    ':age' => '18',
    ':age2' => true
];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO posts (title, body, author, is_published) VALUES (:fname, :sname, :age, :age2)';
$statement = $pdoConn->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute($data);

/*
SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;
'posts', 'CREATE TABLE `posts` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `title` char(255) NOT NULL,\n  `body` text NOT NULL,\n  `author` char(255) NOT NULL,\n  `is_published` tinyint(1) DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
posts, CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `author` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_published` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


*/
```

Comment: In MySQL, there is in reality no `true` or `false`, but `1` and `0`. Have you tried with that instead?

Comment: Your `is_published` column also would indicate you should cast `:age2` to integer first. You could try to disable emulated prepared statements though.

Comment: @Qirel I agree with your statement, but how do you explain it working with `true` as value?

Comment: After execute, try $statement->errorInfo()[2] to see any errors?

Comment: The issue is that your column is data type `tinyint(1)`. You could cast the boolean to an int like so: `':age2' => (int) true`

Comment: the code for creation of the db is resulted by 'show create table posts' which interestingly says the the particular field is tiny int altough I defined it to be boolean. I have tried it again created the same table and defined the same field to be boolean not a tiny int and when I run 'show create table tableName' it shows is_published field as tiny int... weird behaviour... By the way I took your idea to cast the boolean value to number.. thanks

Comment: By the way if I do '$stmt->bindParam(':age2', $bolleanValue, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);' then I can insert false and true both